# Probability of picking 3 balls from 3 buckets

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have 3 buckets with billiards balls placed as below

- Bucket 1: Balls 1 to 5
- Bucket 2: Balls 6 to 10
- Bucket 3: Balls 11 to 15

1. What is the probability of picking 3 balls at random with one from each bucket?
2. What is the probability of picking 3 balls at random with one from each bucket, with replacement?

Thanks in advance.

What I tried:

The probability of choosing 1st bucket is 1/3
probability of choosing 2nd bucket is 1/3
probability of choosing 3rd bucket is 1/3

Probability of picking up a ball from 1st bucket = 1/5.

Probability of picking up a ball from 2nd bucket = 1/5

Probability of picking up a ball from 3rd bucket = 1/5

So,

Probability of choosing one from 1st bucket

( probability of choosing 1st bucket) x (probability of choosing one ball from 1st bucket) .

(1/3)* (1/5)= 1/15.

similarly from 2nd bucket

(1/3) * (1/5) = 1/15

similarly from 3rd bucket

(1/3)*(1/5) = 1/15

The final probability of picking 3 balls from 3 buckets

1/15 + 1/15 + 1/15 = 3/15

Comment: What have you tried?  Note:  I'm not sure the problem is clear.  How are you selecting the balls?  Is it "without replacement" for part $1$?

Comment: HINT for 1) divide the number of ways to pick one from each bucket by the number of ways to pick 3 from all 15

Comment: I pick 3 balls at random no selection. And yes the first one is without replacement

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. The "probability of picking 3 balls" is 1 if you pick 3 balls.

Comment: What does "picking three balls at random" *mean*?  How are they actually selected?

Comment: To amplify on the previous comment: if we put all 15 balls in one bucket, I could shake the bucket vigorously, reach in without looking and stir the balls around, then (still without looking) grasp whichever ball I can and draw it from the bucket. It is reasonable to suppose the each ball has an equal chance of being chosen, and if I reach in a second and third time, each ball in the bucket at _that_ time has an equal chance to be chosen. But if I have three buckets, what's the procedure? I can only reach into one bucket at a time.

Comment: Are you suggesting that a bucket is chosen at random, and a ball is then drawn from that bucket at random for each draw?

Comment: I am so sorry for not making it clear. Yes a bucket is chosen at random and a ball is picked at random from the bucket per event/draw.

Comment: @ Graham I am sorry but I don't understand what selection. I am kind of confused here. Should there be a selection. I can just pick a ball at random without a selection condition. Thats my understanding. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @David I also thought about the process of putting all the balls in one bag. But my thought process there was if that was the problem why are there 3 buckets in the first place.

Comment: I also assume there is some point to having three buckets, but it is not clear what the point is. It is possible that you have neglected some important statement in the source of this problem. You could try editing the question to rewrite the problem statement in the exact words you received it in; you could check earlier exercises or examples from the same source to see if they have multiple buckets and say more about what to do with them. If this is from a textbook, the book title, edition, author's name, and page number could also be useful.